# suggestion: search fist character inside a mark

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using suggestion of this page: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
I have a list like below

```
 var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript (bang ping)",
  "AppleScript (htore) ",
  "Asp (biga) ",
  "BASIC (single)",
  "Erlang (total lang) ",
  "Fortran (total tran)",
 ];
```

I want to search the first characters inside (...) .
Example: typing

b: ->show:  ActionScript (bang ping),  Asp (biga)

s: ->show: BASIC (single)

to: -> show: Erlang (total lang) ,Fortran (total tran)

How i can do ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overrides the default filter

```
$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function (array, term) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("\\(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
        return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nEx5R/